# How to pass navigation via a method?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react-navigation and I would like to pass "navigation" as a props so I could use it. Because when I tried to use it in the other compo It is throwing an error message saying "undefined this.props.navigation etc.."

So here is what I would like to do

```js
            goto={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ChatBox', {
                avatarUrl: matches.avatarUrl,
                name: matches.name,
                navigation: this.props.navigation 
              })}
```

As you can see I'm passing navigation via props to my compo named 'ChatBox'. But the problem is that my 'ChatBox' compo is not receiving the navigation. Could someone help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts I think you missed out on.

1. Every component mentioned in the stack navigator class gets a navigation object in its scope. You can access the same by using `this.props.navigation()`
2. If you need to pass navigation object to any other screen not mentioned in the  stack navigator class, you'll be required to provide it as props, such as `<Chatbox navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

In your case, your navigation object is correctly being sent, just that you are fetching it wrongly in your Chatbox component. Your navigation as a prop is encapsulated in the navigation object itself ( .i.e. its present in `this.props.navigation.state.params.navigation` ) and since you haven't mentioned `Chatbox` component in your stack navigator class, you can't reference the navigation object as it is currently out of scope.

So,

1. You can replace a component by rendering the `<Chatbox/>` component and provide it the props ( as mentioned in point 2 above ) instead of navigating to the component.
2. If you need to navigate to the component, you'll be required to define the `Chatbox` screen in the stack navigator class and then you can use your navigation object.